# MySQL query to find out if part of a string is not numeric

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to find a way to run a query which selects where the first two characters of an eight character string are Not numeric.

I've found a way to select if the entire string is numeric:

```
SELECT str FROM tbl
WHERE str REGEXP('(^[0-9]+$)');
```

So from my limited knowledge of regex I'm guessing that I'll need to use something like:

```
SELECT str FROM tbl
WHERE str REGEXP('(^[A-Z]+$)');
```

(I'm OK to use capitals for this as thats how the codes are stored)

I just don't know how to apply this test to just the first 2 characters of the string instead of the entire string?

Comment: LOL! Yep that worked, as I said my regex knowledge is very limited - that works a treat, thankyou. =D

Comment: Then I suggest you read a bit about regexes and what the chars and groups like `^`, `$` and `{2}` mean. For example [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) can be a good start. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I will do - I've always got by using PHP functions but theres no avoiding them for complex selects in MySQL :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[A-Z]{2}
```

Try this.This should do it.